# How to configure the WHM server as I am having some email issues

Tags: cpanel, vps, whm

I recently bought a VPS server from Godaddy. We have 2 website Kiabza.com & Kishcogroup.com. For Kiabza we have emails in our cpanel and for Kishcogroup we have bought Godaddy professional emails.

Now the problem is when we send mail from Kiabza to Kishcogroup or from kishcogroup to kiabza it bounces back saying no user found. The rest is all working fine.

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEW1z.jpg)

[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqQ4J.jpg)

[error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbGBW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Web-Host Manager (WHM) (probably located at (Kiabza.com/whm). Click on the email icon on the dashboard and navigate to Mail Delivery Reports. You can enter search requirements if you'd like, or you can just hit 'Run Report' without changing anything. Then, locate one of the emails that are bouncing back. What does it say in the 'Result' column? It should either say 'Accepted' or tell you what the problem is. Post the result here and I can help you determine the solution.

Comment: i have posed the screenshot. Please check and let me know thnx.

Comment: From what I can tell from the images, the issue seems to be with the kishcogroup.com domain name. Can you verify that you have an MX record properly setup in that domains DNS zone as well as verify that the account owner for that domain has email abilities enabled?

Comment: actually we are having a VPS server in which 1 ip address is to Kiabza.com and other is to Kishcogroup.com. So if i create email account in Kishcogroup cpanel then the mail from kiabza goes to kishcogroup cpanel email, but i have kishcogroup mails in godaddy professional email. So i want it to redirect the mails to Kishcogroup godaddy professional email.

Comment: Go to WHM Home > DNS Functions > Edit MX Entry and select kishcogroup.com. Can you tell me which Mail Exchanger is being used and what the MX values are? I believe these should be using GoDaddy's MX records

Comment: It may also be beneficial to run the exim bt command from the command line ln your 'manish@kishcogroup.com' email if you have access. From the command line, run ```exim -bt manish@kishcogroup.com``` and it should show you how your server is trying to communicate with that email and show it's MX records and priority order.